# Azure: Updated ASP.Net Core SDK to 1.0 to 2.1.203 and getting error about System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I updated and migrated my local project to start using ASP CORE 2.1.0 from 1.0. I followed the ASP CORE migration guideline from Microsoft here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Then 2.0 to 2.1 here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1

And everything works just fine on my local machine.

After pushing the code, it builds and runs just fine. So no error occurred when running the website. But when I hit the website on my browser, Azure is throwing 500 internal error messages. I checked the logs, and this is what I find:

```
2018-08-01 07:05:25.682 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: 
Connection id "0HLFNDIE4UDCG", Request id "0HLFNDIE4UDCG:00000003": An 
unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'System.Data.SqlClient'
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List`1 assemblies)
        at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
        ...
```

I tried adding System.Data.SqlClient to my local code using Nuget, and pushed to Azure, and still I get the same problem.

Can someone please explain what's happening here? And why Azure needs this package when it's not part of my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a reference path issue.

Check for System.Data.SqlClient in the references and verify the location form which the package is referred. It looks like the path is there in your local machine and not available after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I could do.

I went into the azure console, and typed this in:

```
nuget install System.Data.SqlClient
```

And it added the package into the system. The error now stopped.